# Testing while for multiple conditions (C language)

Tags: c, while-loop, boolean-logic

I have to create a menu wherein if the input is not valid. It should keep asking for a valid input. I've written it below (in C)

```
   #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    printf("What would you like to do? \n 1 (Subtraction) \n 2 (Comparison) \n 3 (Odd/Even) \n 4 (Exit) \n ");
    scanf_s("%d", &input);

    while (input != 1 || input != 2 || input != 3|| input != 4)
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid option \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &input);
}   // At this point, I think it should keep testing variable input and if it's not either 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. It would keep looping.
```

But what's happening is it loops even when the input is, for example, 2.

Comment: your while condition is always `true` since every input is either different from 1 or from 2. You should change `||` with `&&`.

Comment: Your loop will stop if input equals 1 *and* 2 *and* 3 *and* 4 (at the same time). This is not possible. So it'll loop forever.

Comment: @Franck But if I input 2, doesn't that make the condition not true in this case?

Comment: No, if your input is 2, `input != 2` will return `false`, but `input != 1` will return `true`. As `true || false` is `true`, your final result is `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is saying: Loop as long as the following is true:

```
(input != 1 || input != 2 || input != 3 || input != 4)
```

Turning this around the code says: Break the loop if the above condition is false, which is true for

```
!(input != 1 || input != 2 || input != 3 || input != 4)
```

Now let's apply [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to the above expression and we'll get the logical equal expression (as the loop's break condition):

```
(input == 1 && input == 2 && input == 3 && input == 4)
```

The loop will break if the above is true. It is true if `input` equals `1` and `2` and `3` and `4` at the same time. This is not possible, so the loop will run forever.

> But what's happening is it loops even when the input is, for example, 2.

If `input` is `2` it's still unequal `1`, `3` and `4`, which makes the loop-condition become true and looping goes on. :-)

---

Not related to your issue:

As you want the loop's code to be execute at least once, you ought to use  a `do {...} while`-loop.

```
do
{
    printf("Please enter a valid option \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
} while (!(input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3 || input == 4))
```

or (following De Morgan again):

```
do
{
    printf("Please enter a valid option \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
} while (input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4)
```

or even tighter:

```
do
{
    printf("Please enter a valid option \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
} while (input < 1 || input > 4)
```

Comment: I love the DeMorgan's Law usage! Quite a nice explanation here.

Comment: @alk your first do while code is saying while input not equal to 1 and 2 and 3 and 4. Do something. Which means the do part will be executed even when I input 3. Because it is not equal to 3 AND 4 right?

Comment: @alk I think that little ! in the while statement was the solution to the problem. I'll test it and see. Fank bruh.

Comment: @Ansh: It's not just the `!` which is different form your code. Please look twice.

Comment: @alk FYI, your first do while is wrong in C. Shows an error on the exclamation point. 

Your second code works but it does do first...just needs a little tweaking..Works like a charm doe. Upped!

Comment: @Ansh: Fixed this by just adding a pair wrapping parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

What you've written is that if the variable is not either one of them, you loop.
What you want is `while(input < 1 || 4 < input)` or `while(input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4)`

Comment: My input will never be 1 and 2 and 3 and 4. It will be either one of them. So won't an and not make sense either?

Comment: If you enter 2 for instance, it will evaluate to true, since input != 1 is true. If you use my examples however, you will see the it evaluates to false, since even though input != 1 is true, because of the AND with input != 2. You should run it in your IDE against some inputs, maybe that'll help you understand your problem better

Comment: @Ansh you want all of the conditions to be true simultaneously: `input` differs from all of the options